# compiling assignment expression to bytecode

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, bytecode, interpreter

I am trying to wrap my head around compiling a assignment expression to bytecode. I am writing my own language, and this part has really got me stumped. My language takes the source code and converts it into tokens, which are converted directly to bytecode. For example, something like:

```
a + 2
```

becomes

```
TOKEN_NAME
TOKEN_ADD
TOKEN_INT
```

this would then be parsed and converted to bytecode which would look something like

```
LOAD_VARIABLE (this is the a)
LOAD_CONSTANT (this is the 2)
ADD
```

This is pretty straight forward. But for an assignment expression such as:

```
a[0][1] = 2
```

which would become

```
TOKEN_NAME
TOKEN_L_BRACKET
TOKEN_INT
TOKEN_R_BRACKET
TOKEN_L_BRACKET
TOKEN_INT
TOKEN_R_BRACKET
TOKEN_ASSIGN
TOKEN_INT
```

I need to load a, do a subscript on that object (the 0 subscript), then store 2 into 1 subscript. I should add that the parser is effectively LL(1), which makes this particularly difficult.

I cannot think of a way to make sure the last part of the left hand side expression (the part I am assigning to) isn't loaded, but has the value (2) stored into it.

If any of this is unclear, please leave a comment I will be happy to clarify my program. (It's pretty hard to make a MCVE for an entire interpreter for a programming language!)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you get the assign token, then go back to the first name or brackets?

Comment: It's an LL(1) parser therefore I can't backtrack. In actual code, these expressions could be absolutely huge between the subscripts, so going back would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: you cannot backtrack but you can _store_ the tokens in an aux list.

Comment: that might work for subscript but im not sure if it was something like `x = 2` how i would be able to make sure i stored 2 in x, and not loaded x first

Comment: You probably cannot convert *directly* from tokens to bytecode, in the sense of emitting bytecode for each token without sometimes needing to first scan an indefinite number of subsequent tokens.  The usual approach is to first build an AST, or at least a fragment of one, and then use that to generate (byte)code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have previously written projects which use an AST, however in most circumstances, it uses unnecessary memory and creates unnecessary overhead. Other languages such as wren have managed to compile straight to bytecode from tokens.

Comment: @DanielGee, consider the expression `a + b * c * d`.  Supposing the usual operator precedence (or if precedence is forced via parentheses), the `ADD` instruction cannot be emitted until after the instructions corresponding to the next *five* tokens.  It can be deferred an indefinite amount by extending the chain of multiplication operations.  This is only scratching the surface.  This arises in part from the fact that you are converting infix language syntax to postfix bytecode.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this is why I have multiple functions, just like in a normal AST parser. In this simple example I would have 3 functions. `parse_addition`, `parse_multiplication` and `parse_int`. `parse addition` would compile the lhs, then the rhs, then emit ADD. those lhs and rhs would be calls to `parse_multiplication`. that function would do the same as `parse_addition`, except its lhs and rhs are `parse_int`, which parses the integers. this way, the compiler keeps order of operation without violating LL(1), as it checks for the operator only after parsing the lhs.

Comment: Well that sounds like a recursive-descent parser, @DanielGee, not an LL(1).  A recursive descent parser builds an AST, too, but it is embodied on the call stack via a series of stack frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple backtracking method to construct references:

- compile the expression as if you were reading the expression
- if the next operation requires an lvalue, look back at the last bytecode operation
- convert this last operation according to this table:

  - `LOAD_VALUE` converts to `GET_VALUE_REF`
  - `LOAD_PROPERTY` converts to `GET_PROPERTY_REF` (`LOAD_PROPERTY` is generated by `a.b`)
  - `LOAD_ELEMENT` converts to `GET_ELEMENT_REF` (`LOAD_ELEMENT` is generated by `a[b]`)
  - any other opcode generates an invalid lvalue error.

This method is sufficient for the most common semantics. For C you would add support for the dereferencing operator `*`: `GET_POINTER_VALUE` converts to `GET_POINTER_REF` which is essentially a no op.

To implement this you need to keep track of the last opcode generated by the compiler, with the possibility to patch it into another byte code.

The expression `a[0][2]` would compile to

```
LOAD_VARIABLE a (this is the a)
LOAD_CONSTANT 0 (this is the 0)
GET_ELEMENT
LOAD_CONSTANT 2 (this is the 2)
GET_ELEMENT
```

`a[0][2] = 3` converts to

```
LOAD_VARIABLE a
LOAD_CONSTANT 0
GET_ELEMENT
LOAD_CONSTANT 2
GET_ELEMENT_REF
LOAD_CONSTANT 3
STORE_REF
```

You can also generate specific stores directly if you don't need a reference (you need a reference for `a[b] += c` for example).

`a[0][2] = 3` then converts to

```
LOAD_VARIABLE a
LOAD_CONSTANT 0
GET_ELEMENT
LOAD_CONSTANT 2
LOAD_CONSTANT 3
STORE_ELEMENT (uses 3 stack slots)
```

while `a[0][2] += 3` produces:

```
LOAD_VARIABLE a
LOAD_CONSTANT 0
GET_ELEMENT
LOAD_CONSTANT 2
GET_ELEMENT_REF
LOAD_REF
LOAD_CONSTANT 3
ADD
STORE_REF
```